# Sorting column triggers click to run Macro...How do I fix this?

Tags: vba, excel, cell, columnsorting

I have some code that runs a macro when certain cells are clicked.  The problem is that sorting a column also causes the macro to run.  How can I prevent this code from running when a column is sorted?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AI13:AI10000")) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Hello World!"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm pretty sure it's irrelevant, but the rest of my code is simply for taking values from one workbook and using it to filter pivot tables in another workbook.

Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I think that you should show that sorting code. So, we can solve easily.

Comment: How are you determining that certain cells are clicked?  `Worksheet_SelectionChange`?  If so, this is intended behavior as the cells move around while being sorted.  Can you included the code for however you are detecting the event?  Please [edit] that detail into the question.

Comment: Thanks Byron, that was correct.  I didn't realize I had copy pasted the wrong sub name.

To fix the problem I replaced `Worksheet_Selectionchange` with `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick`.  This required a double click vice a single click, but prevented the macro from running when I didn't want it to.

Comment: Sounds like you fixed it?  Can you add your solution as answer and accept it?  Helps folks in the future and those of us looking for unanswered questions.

Comment: Thanks Byron, I added my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting will trigger `Worksheet_SelectionChange` because the range is selected in the sorting process.  Using `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` instead will run the macro with a double click on the desired cell and the event will not be triggered by sorting.

The following code worked for me:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AI13:AI10000")) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Hello World!"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```